# Read a string and display the vowels and the consonants in it

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have as an assignment to read a string and to display the string of vowels and the string of consonants that are in that string. For example, if i have the string: aaceb, the string of vowels would be: aae and the string of consonants would be: cb. I have tried something on my own, but i have some errors (error starting in line 3 in command) and i can't figure it out why. Many thanks in advance :D

```
set serveroutput on
accept p_sir prompt "Sir=";
declare 
v varchar2(20):=&p_sir;
vocale varchar2(20);
consoane varchar2(20);
c varchar2(1);

begin
 for i in 1..length(v) loop
  c:=substr(v,i,1);
  case
    when c='a' then vocale:=vocale||c;
    when c='e' then vocale:=vocale||c;
    when c='i' then vocale:=vocale||c;
    when c='o' then vocale:=vocale||c;
    when c='u' then vocale:=vocale||c;
    else consoane:=consoane||c;
end case;

--dbms_output.put_line(c);
end loop;

dbms_output.put_line('vocale: ' ||vocale||' consoane:'||consoane);
end;
/
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I think you need something similar to [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811759/read-a-string-and-display-the-vowels-and-the-consonants-in-it) but instead one array use two to separate vowel and consonants.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 17:
PLS-00201: identifier 'AACEB' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 8, column 20:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 8, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Is this for a PL/SQL class you are taking? This is trivial work for SQL (and you can use the same functions in PL/SQL). For example, to get the string of consonants, use `translate(input_string, 'zAEIOUaeiou', 'z')` - that replaces each wowel with nothing (`null`), so the result is just the consonants from the input string. If there may also be other symbols (space, + etc.) that must be removed, add them to the list in `TRANSLATE`.

Comment: I prefer the TRANSLATE option for doing this within SQL, but your script will work if you add quotes on the usage of the input variable.  v varchar2(20):='&p_sir';

Comment: Just for learning purpose, you could simplify your `CASE` with something like `when c in ('a', 'e', ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Proof of concept:

```
SQL> begin
  2  dbms_output.put_line(translate('mathguy', 'zAEIOUaeiou', 'z'));
  3  end;
  4  /

mthgy

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: OP need also the vowels string. I dont understand what does, but looks very efficient

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - If OP or anyone else understands how this works (to get just the consonants), then it should be trivial to adapt it to get the vowels. I generally try to show folks how to do things, I don't try to do ALL the work for them. THEN: I don't know what you mean by "I don't understand what [it] does" - do you mean you are not familiar with TRANSLATE? It's a standard Oracle function. The 'z' is needed due to a weird behavior of this function; there should be no 'z' but if the third argument is empty, the function returns NULL regardless of the other two arguments.

Comment: yes, im not familiar with translate. The `z` looks very weird. And looks for do the vowels string will need to put all the chars.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm

Comment: The `z` is explained in the documentation (I just posted a link to it). Yes, for vowels you need to show all the consonants in the list. However, TRANSLATE is much faster than any REGEXP solution. Of course, for this exercise it doesn't matter, but in real life it may make a significant difference.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - and, to clarify: since this is a learning exercise, not something for production, I offered this solution because it will help the OP (and anyone else at the same stage of learning SQL) by demonstrating the use of TRANSLATE. Many people just learn regular expressions, and they are surprised when someone rewrites their queries and they run much faster. REGEXP is the only thing they were taught, so they have no idea there are other tools.

Comment: For the vowels you could nest two translate calls; something like `translate(input_string, 'a' || translate(input_string, 'zAEIOUaeiou', 'z'), 'a')`. Not so elegant, but maybe better than typing all the consonants.

Comment: @Aleksej - I don't see the problem with typing all the consonants. But that is not really the point; in real life it is more likely that one would use something like this to remove all non-printable characters from the input, or all single-quotes, etc. The point is TRANSLATE itself, not its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to:

- remove the non-vowels `[^aeiou]` to be left with only the vowels.
- remove the vowels `[aeiou]` and non-alphabetic characters `[^a-z]` to be left with only the consonants.

Like this:

```
DECLARE
  v_text VARCHAR2(200) := 'Your text string';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    'Vowels: ' || REGEX_REPLACE( v_text, '[^aeiou]', NULL, 1, 0, 'i' )
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
    'Consonants: ' || REGEX_REPLACE( v_text, '[aeiou]|[^a-z]', NULL, 1, 0, 'i' )
  );
END;
/
```